# How to add an array to an existing collection in mongoDb

Tags: mongodb, database, nosql

I need to add an array of data to an existing collection in mongoDb.

suppose my existing collection, say "planetSystem" is of type:

```
{
     "_id":"123123123",
     "key1":"value1",
     "key2":"value2" 
}
```

i need to add an array of the following type

```
[
    {
        "amount":"678",
        "addedBy":"idontknow"
        "commission":"100"
    } ,
    {
        "amount":"800",
        "addedBy":"iwishiknew"
        "commission":"108"
    } 
]
```

so that the final collection looks like this

```
{
    "_id":"123123123",
    "key1":"value1",
    "key2":"value2",
    [
      {
        "amount":"678",
        "addedBy":"idontknow"
        "commission":"100"
      } ,
      {
        "amount":"800",
        "addedBy":"iwishiknew"
        "commission":"108"
      }
    ] 
}
```

i need help in the update query part of this.
Thanks

Comment: You need to add the array to a key. Take a look at this [MongoDB : Playing With Arrays](http://tgrall.github.io/blog/2015/04/21/mongodb-playing-with-arrays/)

Answer (score 0):

You will have to add key to PlanetSystem collection,

```
var planetSystem= {
 "_id":"123123123",
 "key1":"value1",
 "key2":"value2" };

var arr = [{
    "amount":"678",
    "addedBy":"idontknow"
    "commission":"100"
} ,
{
    "amount":"800",
    "addedBy":"iwishiknew"
    "commission":"108"
}];
```

Add new key

```
planetSystem.arr = arr;
```

Result,

```
var planetSystem={
"_id": "123123123",
"key1": "value1",
"key2": "value2",
"arr": [{
    "amount": "678",
    "addedBy": "idontknow",
    "commission": "100"
}, {
    "amount": "800",
    "addedBy": "iwishiknew",
    "commission": "108"
}]}
```